# MySQL use result of query in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

In my database I have a table called `data_countries` with the following structure:

```
country | population | nearby_country1 | nearby_country2 | nearby_country3
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT data_countries.country, data_countries.population, data_countries.nearby_country1 , data_countries.nearby_country2 , data_countries.nearby_country3 
FROM data_countries
WHERE data_countries.country = 'Netherlands'
```

I get a result that looks something like this

```
Netherlands    | 16570613 | Belgium     | Germany | United Kingdom
```

What I actually want to achieve now is the following.
Based on the input 'Netherlands', I also want to return the data in the same stucture for column `nearby_country1` `nearby_country2` and `nearby_country3`.

So concretely, I want to adapt my query to get an output like this:

```
Netherlands    | 16570613 | Belgium     | Germany | United Kingdom
Belgium        | 10000000 | Netherlands | Other   | Other  
Germany        | 10000000 | Netherlands | Other   | Other  
United Kingdom | 10000000 | Other       | Other   | Netherlands
```

I looked into `INNER JOIN` and `Subselect` and tried some things but can't seem to get it right.
Hopefully someone can put me into the right direction on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuck.  Your data is not normalized so you need to do this with joins.  Here is one way if your table is not very big.  Note that the country itself is included in the "nearby" countries:

```
select nearby.*
from data_countries c join
     data_countries nearby
     on c.country = 'Netherlands' and
        nearby.country in (c.country, c.nearby_country1, c.nearby_country2, c.nearby_country3)
order by (nearby.country = 'Netherlands') desc;
```

If you want to keep the ordering, then change the `order by` to:

```
order by (nearby.country = 'Netherlands') desc,
         (nearby.country = c.nearby_country1) desc,
         (nearby.country = c.nearby_country2) desc,
         (nearby.country = c.nearby_country3) desc
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28392) is a SQL Fiddle example showing it working (note this uses SQL Server just so I can use the `with` syntax).

Normalized means that you have a table called `NearbyCountries`, with two data columns.  One for the first country and one for the second.

Comment: hey countries is not a table here ?

Comment: why did you assigned select neaby * from countries ?

Comment: What do you mean with normalized? I changed the question a bit. All data in my columns contain the same type of data.
Also it is all in one table. so

Comment: Thanks, it works like this.. I will need to do some research so I can understand what actually happens. For now you helped me very much.
Do you suggest I should look into normalization?

Comment: @rvroo . . . If you are going to use relational databases, then you should understand normalization.  For this particular problem, it would help a bit, but you might have other considerations.